# Android: Catching uncaught exception, sending stacktrace to server, and still using default behavior

Tags: android, exception, android-service, uncaught-exception

Is doing all of this in one possible? I can't seem to get this to work. This is how I am catching uncaught exceptions:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler;

public void onCreate() {
    defaultHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
            handleUncaughtException(thread, e);
        }
    });
}


public void handleUncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    Intent crashReportIntentService = new Intent(this, SendCrashReportIntentService.class);
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String s = writer.toString();
    crashReportIntentService.putExtra(SendCrashReportIntentService.STACK_TRACE, s);
    startService(crashReportIntentService);

    defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);// let the default handle it and crash the app
}
}
```

So I catch it, get the stack trace, then attempt to fire off a service. After I call startService I call defaultHandler.uncaughtException() so that the default "Unfortunately this app has crashed" message will pop up. However, it seems my service is never called.

This is what part of my service looks like:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "***** SendCrashReportIntentService: In onHandleIntent!");

    handleUncaughtException(intent.getStringExtra(STACK_TRACE));
}
```

I have breakpoints but this is never called and I'm getting no hits in my database.

Comment: Are you seeing the "Unfortunately this app has crashed" message?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing that message.

Comment: OK...just a guess. As an `IntentService` uses a worker thread, starting one is effectively an asynchronous procedure. Because of that the call to `startService(...)` will return immediately and your call to the default UncaughtExceptionHandler will happen immediately after that and effectively crash the app (as you intended). Is it possible that means your `IntentService` is prevented from running correctly as a result of you allowing the crash?

Comment: Seems like that would make sense. I'll see if I can find a different way to go about it.

Comment: I'd try moving `defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);` out of your `Application` where it is called after `startService(...)` in to the `onHandleIntent(...)` method of your `IntentService`. Put it after your call to `handleUncaughtException(intent.getStringExtra(STACK_TRACE));`. In theory that would allow the call to your server to upload the data and then it would trigger the crash. You'd need to make `defaultHandler` as `public static` so you can call it from the `IntentService`.